# When I import prettytable, an issue

Tags: python

There is an issue that says:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PrettyTable'
```

When I:

```
import prettytable
```

Could you tell me some advice?
Thank a lot!!

Comment: Please show us the whole code and the full traceback

Comment: [root@localhost python_test]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 10 2013, 22:48:45) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import prettytable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "prettytable.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = prettytable.PrettyTable(["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"])  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PrettyTable'

Comment: import prettytable
x = prettytable.PrettyTable(["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"])

x.align["City name"] = "l" # Left align city names  
x.padding_width = 1 # One space between column edges and contents (default)  
x.add_row(["Adelaide",1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane",5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
x.add_row(["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9])
x.add_row(["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4])
print x
It also appear the same mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overriden the actual module `prettytable` by naming your file `prettytable.py`. Thus, when you try to `import prettytable`, you're trying to import your file.

Change the name of your file and also delete the `.pyc` it created.

Comment: Could you tell me the reason why it can not works when I override the actual module ??

Comment: @changzhi Because then, when you do `import prettytable`, it imports your file and not the actual module you want to import